# Having some trouble with .click()

Tags: jquery

I have some trouble with `.click()`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class='some-class'>
   <textarea class='text'></textarea>
   <button class='save-btn'>save</button>
</div>
<div class='some-class'>
   <textarea class='text'></textarea>
   <button class='save-btn'>save</button>
</div>
```

```js
$('.save-btn').click(function(){
     var value = $(this).prev('.text').val();
     printText(value);
});

function printText(value){
   console.log(value)
}
```

This code prints `value` 2 times. I can't understand why it's happened. 
May be someone could help me to print `value` only for one time?

Comment: can't reproduce this issue. it is printing the value only ony in this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z0trz7L1/)

Comment: for me either only once... what browser do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to log clicking only once..Change this..

```
var printed  = false;

function printText(value){
    if(printed) return;
   console.log(value);
   printed  = true;
}
```